# Specifing return activity for implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

I have a implicit intent where it opens a website and after they finish using the website, I want it to get open a particular activity, irrespective of their parent activity. I just want to know how to make this happen.

Comment: `startActivityForResult` and then handle `responseCode` in `onActivityResult`

Comment: But, I have to call the same intent from various activities. In the case you have mentioned, I have to use the onActivityResult in each activity. I am thinking of setting FLAGS or parent activity to perform the same.

Comment: no, you have to use `onActivityResult` in parent activity only

Comment: The sequence would be: parent activity(which has onActivityResultMethod) -> activity with webview -> parent activity (which has onActivityResultMethod) -> new child activity after handling responsecode